# encrypt and decrypt aes with iphone and javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, encryption, aes

I'm trying to figure out to encrypt and decrypt between ios and javascript. I've been using http://dotmac.rationalmind.net/2009/02/aes-interoperability-between-net-and-iphone/ and http://cryptojs.altervista.org/secretkey/doc/doc_aes_nodejs.html in order to see if they would work. I've look around and tried other code presented, but with no luck.

Comment: Without code how can we help to you. Please post some portion of your code so we can check or post sample project.

Comment: Post it here, don't use pastebin if possible, outside links are discouraged for information that is required to answer the question.

Comment: what is the value of this constant: kChosenCipherBlockSize?

Comment: kChosenCipherBlockSize = kCCBlockSizeAES128